# Flask: Not able to access requests using nginx and directly I am able to access

Tags: python, linux, docker, nginx, flask

I am setting up Flask, uwsgi, and nginx

Below is the config setup for uwsgi

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

protocol = http
socket = 0.0.0.0:8443

buffer-size=32768

die-on-term = true

enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
```

When I try to Get Request , it is working fine

```
# curl --location --request GET 'http://10.1.1.10:8443/info?id=1&subid=2'
```

I have created ubuntu (docker container)

```
# access from nginx docker container with same curl working fine 
# curl --location --request GET 'http://10.1.1.10:8443/info?id=1&subid=2'
```

Next, I have installed nginx, configured like below

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/flaskconfig
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 80;
    # the IP Address your site will be served on
    server_name 10.1.1.10;
    # Proxy connections to application server
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 10.1.1.10:8443;
    }
}
```

Created Linked file

```
# mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
# ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/flaskconfig /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com
```

Restarted nginx service and service is running

I also Cross verified nginx with "nginx -t" command, config is good

```
  nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
  nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

It is not working, when  I tried to access from nginx proxy and below is curl command

```
# curl --location --request GET 'http://10.1.1.10:8080/info?id=1&subid=2' 


Note: why 8080 port is because nginx host container is started from -p 8080:80 and also tried with port 80 in above same  curl , no luck
```

I guess, It is something wrong with nginx config/setup and I am unable to figure it out, struck from almost 2 days, Any help is really appreciated

message  /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
    2020/12/04 17:18:17 [error] 1195#1195: *3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.10.1.16, server: 10.1.1.10, request: "GET /info?id=1&subid=2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://10.1.1.10:8443", host: "10.1.1.10:8080"
```

Another Note:

Only Ngnix is running in Docker and both will accessing host and docker from outside is 10.1.1.10 IP, if we need to access ngnix i need pass 10.1.1.10:8080, if i need access uwsgi then 10.1.1.10:8443

Comment: What's the IP address 10.1.1.10?  You mention Docker once or twice in here; which part is running in a container (or are both?), and how are you starting the container(s)?

Comment: Only Ngnix is running in Docker and both will accessing host and docker from outside is 10.1.1.10 IP, if we need to access ngnix i need pass 10.1.1.10:8080, if i need access uwsgi then 10.1.1.10:8443